# Restricting one URL from Apcahe httpd reverse proxy rules

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have Apache server serving as a reverse proxy for one of Angular application.

Defined Reverse proxy rules in ssl.conf like below

ProxyPass http://10.10.10.101/xyz/abc
 ProxyPassReverse http://10.10.10.101/xyz/abc

And also defined Rewrite conditions

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xyz/abc(.*)$

But in my code i have one file coming with same URL like /xyz/abc/header.html.

I want to restrict that URL not to go through reverse proxy rule.

How can i restrict it, can some one help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To make exceptions to proxy you just append "!" at the end, like:

```
ProxyPass /xyz/abc/header.html !
```